# How to install bind9 with DLZ Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: mysql, bind, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install bind 9 with Dynamically Loadable Zones (DLZ) as the native bind does not have such capabilities. Found a source of compilation on Ubuntu 11.10 but it doesn't seem to work.

can't find a decent tutorial or guide on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very sad that Ubuntu decided to drop the DLZ support out of their bind9 package since Ubuntu 12.04.

So I had to do my own build (using Ubuntus source package and build options). It isn't too complicated. The following works on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 (tested only with the LDAP-module, but Mysql should work too):

Please remove first an installation of bind if you already have it:

```
sudo apt-get remove bind9
```

Then get the compile environment:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

Get the sources:

```
mkdir ~/bind9
cd ~/bind9
apt-get source bind9
cd bind9-9.8.1.dfsg.P1  # may be different for a newer version
```

You have to add the DLZ-support:

```
vi debian/rules
8<--- snip --->8
...
configure-stamp:
        dh_testdir
        ./configure --prefix=/usr \
                --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man \
                ...
                **–with-dlz-ldap=yes** \
                $(EXTRA_FEATURES)
...
8<--- snap --->8
```

You have to add a `--with-dlz-...=yes` for each needed DLZ module. This may be:

- ldap
- filesystem
- postgres
- mysql
- bdb

Now start the build process:

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

The build aborts if some dependencies are missing, add it, e. g.:

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper libtool bison hardening-wrapper
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev libdb-dev libssl-dev libldap2-dev libxml2-dev libcap2-dev libgeoip-dev
```

Retry `dpkg-buildpackage`.

If the build was successful, you can install the package:

```
cd ..
dpkg -i ./bind9_9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.3_i386.deb # may be different for a newer version
```

It is adviced to avoid automatically update of bind:

```
apt-mark hold bind9
```